# create a debounced function that delays invoking func when searching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I create a debounced function that delays invoking func `getTodo`. It writes letters to the input, but nothing happens. In the network tab, also zero requests. Without debounce, the search works.

```
import _, {debounce} from 'lodash';

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
    }
  }

  search = (query) => {
    debounce(() =>  this.getTodo(query), 1000)
  }

  getTodo = (query) => {
    axios({
       url: `/api/v1/todos/{query}`,
       method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => {  
        this.setState({
            todos: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 

  render () {

    return (
        <input onChange={this.search} />    
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debounce is a higher order function that takes another function at wraps it. For debounce to work you need to continuously invoke the new function returned by the debounce (the debounced function). Whenever the debounced function is called, it delays calling the wrapped function by the `wait` time. If it's called again during the `wait` time window, the execution of the wrapped function is delayed again by the same `wait` time and so on. If the `wait` time ends, and the function wasn't called again during that time, the wrapped function is called.

You are creating the debounced function, and you don't invoke it, and this is why nothing happens. The answer by @iagowp's recreates the function all the time, which means that it acts like a `setTimeout` with a delay of 1000ms, and not as a debounced function.

To use debounce correctly, wrap your `getTodo` function with debounce. This will return a new wrapped function, which you invoke as your `onChange` handler:

```
getTodo = debounce((query) => {
  axios({
      url: `/api/v1/todos/{query}`,
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        todos: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
}, 1000);
```

If you want to separate the handler from the server call, you can wrap the `search` method instead:

```
search = debounce((query) => this.getTodo(query), 1000);
```

Comment: I have to use `getTodo = debounce((query) => {`. What should I do with this: `search = (query) => {
  debounce(() =>  this.getTodo(query), 1000)()
}`?

Comment: You don't need the search function at all. I've fixed my answer because I forgot to add the wait time.

Comment: If you want to use the search function, you can wrap it with debounce, you can change it to:
``search = debounce((query) =>  this.getTodo(query), 1000)``
}

Comment: So I can choose either this solution from the answer or this comment?

Comment: Yep. I've updated the answer with the comment code as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce):

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after
>   wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced
>   function was invoked.

You are not invoking the created function, there are 2 solutions:

```
search = (query) => {
  debounce(() =>  this.getTodo(query), 1000)()
}
```

or

```
search = (query) => {
  let debounced = debounce(() =>  this.getTodo(query), 1000)
  debounced();
}
```

For the way you are using it, why not just a `setTimeout`?